# Calling SQL Stored Procedure with Output Parameter in VBScript

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, adodb

I've written a VBScript function to call a stored procedure.  In the past, I've written a number of functions calling stored procedures with input parameters, but in this instance, I need to work with an Output parameter.

In another application, I call the exact same stored procedure using the Entity Framework, so the stored procedure is fine.

Here's my code:

> ```
> Function checkAccess(userid,link)
>     isAllowed = false
>
>     set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
>     cmd.CommandText = "Check_Permission"
>     cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
>     cmd.NamedParameters = true
>     cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
>     cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Login", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, userId))
>     cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@LinkId", adInteger, adParamInput, 50, link))    
>     cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@IsAllowed", adBoolean, adParamOutput, 10, isAllowed))
>
>     checkAccess = isAllowed
> End Function
> ```

This function always returns false.  How do I make it work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should return the value of your output parameter:

```
checkAccess = cmd.Parameters("@IsAllowed").Value
```

Also, output parameters in ADO don't require an initial value and adBoolean parameters don't require a size, so you could change your the last paramter to:

```
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@IsAllowed", adBoolean, adParamOutput))
```

You could also get rid of your isAllowed variable since it is no longer necessary.