# VBscript call stored procedure from MySQL with output parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, vbscript

**[ EDIT 20220219 ]**

Resolved using VBSCRIPT CODE below

```
   SQL = " CALL NewCheckData(@pOld); "
   cn.execute(SQL)   
   
   SQL = " SELECT @pOld; "
   Set RS = cn.execute(SQL)
   
   pOld = cInt(RS("@pOld"))
```

**[ EDIT 20220219 ]**

**[EDIT]**

I have a Stored Procedure on a MySQL DB.

Which simply takes the COUNT ROWS of a Parameter and returns the Value of that Parameter.

I would like to call this Stored Procedure to assign value to variable in my VBscript code.

This is MySql routine (stored procedure) tried and worked.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `NewCheckData`(OUT pOld INT (11))
BEGIN

SELECT
    COUNT(*) tOld INTO pOld
FROM
    `DoTable` 
WHERE
    DATE( myDATE ) = CURRENT_DATE;

END
```

VBSCRIPT CODE is as below

```
   On Error Resume Next
   
   Const adCmdStoredProc = 4
   Const adInteger = 3
   Const adVarWChar = 202
   Const adParamInput = &H0001
   Const adParamOutput = &H0002
   Const adParamReturnValue = &H0004

   Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   cn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=XXX;PORT=3306;DATABASE=XXX;USER=XXX;PASSWORD=XXX;OPTION=3;"  
   cn.CommandTimeout = 10000
   
   Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
   
   With cmd
      Set .ActiveConnection = cn
          .CommandText = "NewCheckData"
          .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
          .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("RETURN_VALUE", adInteger, adParamReturnValue )
          .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@pOld", adInteger, adParamOutput, 11)
          .Execute
          parmval = .Parameters(0).Value
   End With
   
   cn.Close()
   Set cn = Nothing

   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
     WScript.Echo "Error in : " & Err.Description
     Err.Clear
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0
Error or messagebox
```

Error or messagebox

[image]

Any suggestion, please.

**[OLD QUESTION]**

I am working with VBSCRIPT and using stored procedure MySQL.

I have to get the value of stored procedure out parameter.

This is **MySql routine** (*stored procedure*) tried and worked

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `CheckData`(OUT pOld INT (11))
BEGIN

SELECT
    COUNT(*) tOld INTO pOld
FROM
    `DoTable` 
WHERE
    DATE( myDATE ) = CURRENT_DATE;

END
```

VBSCRIPT CODE is as below

```
   Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   cn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=XXX;PORT=3306;DATABASE=XXX;USER=XXX;PASSWORD=XXX;OPTION=3;"  
   cn.CommandTimeout = 1000 

   Set objCommandSec = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
   objCommandSec.ActiveConnection = cn
   objCommandSec.CommandType = 4
   objCommandSec.CommandText = "CheckData"

   objCommandSec.Parameters.Refresh

   objCommandSec.Parameters.append objCommandSec.createParameter("@pOld", adInteger, adParamReturnValue) <<< error line
   objCommandSec.execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
   pOld = objCommandSec.Parameters("@pOld").value

   MsgBox(pOld) 
   
   cn.Close()
   Set cn = Nothing
```

Error or messagebox line 15

```
Error 'Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another'
```

Any suggestion, please.

Comment: You have the wrong `ParameterType` set, it should be `adParamOutput` not `adParamReturnValue`. See [`ParameterDirectionEnum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameterdirectionenum?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @user692942 thanks I have edit the `VBSCRIPT code` from `adParamReturnValue` to `adParamOutput`. Same error

Comment: @Akina True. I have edit the SP in MySql.

Comment: @EdwardSheriffCurtis Think you need to specify the `Size` as well on an `adParamOutput` parameter. Also, have you defined the "ADO Constants", `adInteger`, `adParamOutput` etc? You should have `Const adInteger = 3` for example, as VBScript doesn't know about the ADO named constants automatically.

Comment: @Akina  True. I have edit the SP in MySql. Thanks

Comment: BEGIN-END (and DELIMITER re-assigning) is excess in single-statement stored procedure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling SQL Stored Procedure with Output Parameter in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10017933)

Comment: @user692942 Your suggested link resolve the problem of input parameters not of the out parameters

Comment: Also relevant - [Return a value and a result set from stored procedure classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42070162) (It says Classic ASP, but applies to VBScript also).

Answer (score -1):

Edit: I failed to consider and mention that the below code example is accessing a MS-SQL DB.  The behavior could therfor be different.

I don't use .VBS much anymore, but as I believe you are using the "Windows Script Host" environment I don't think it will make much difference.  In the past I have done essentially the same thing as you demonstrate above many times with WSH & .JS. I also always ran into problems when I explicitly added the parameter definitions.  I have since learned that for me the .refresh() is completely sufficient.  I therefore leave .createParameter out now and simply give the named parameters the needed values as such:

```
var jsADO = {}; 
jsADO.objConn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
jsADO.objConn.Open("Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;...");
jsADO.cmd_insertShare = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");
var cmd = jsADO.cmd_insertShare;
cmd.ActiveConnection = jsADO.objConn;
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc; // 4
cmd.CommandText = "usp_insertShare";
cmd.Prepared = true;
cmd.NamedParameters = true;
cmd.Parameters.Refresh()

...

var sqlRec;
var cmd = jsADO.cmd_insertShare;
cmd.Parameters("@p_Server")      = "myServer";
cmd.Parameters("@p_Name")        = "myShare";
cmd.Parameters("@p_Description") = "myShare Desc";
cmd.Parameters("@p_LocalPath")   = "sharePath";
sqlRec = cmd.Execute(null, null, 0);
```

The syntax is indeed different, but I hope the gist is clear.

In summary, I think you've got it, just try leaving the .createParameter function out and only setting the named parameter values.